# Running IMO in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to run IMO in Ubuntu and found this add on for chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imoim/dajiombagmonlmmnegaafgfimmeofbmg?hl=en

But it doesn't work for me anyway. Is there any way to run it in Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addons doesn't seem to work. Why dont you try using Skype instead, if you are looking for an alternative solution.

https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/skype-for-linux/

It runs quite well for me.